# On the use of Mechanize with a drop down that is not contained within a form

Tags: python, mechanize

```
<div onclick="zctv.GridView.setPopupFlag('date');" id="zc-topbar-date">

        <input readonly="readonly" class="zc-textBox" maxlength="20" size="15" onclick="zctv.GridView.cal.show('zc-topbar-date')" onfocus="this.blur()" value="Mon, Apr. 23" id="dateText"/>

        <input onclick="zctv.GridView.cal.show('zc-topbar-date')" onfocus="this.blur()" type="button" class="zc-dropdown-default" title="Change date to display in grid" id="imgDateDropDown" />

    </div>
```

I'm working with the snippet above with Mechanize. What the code is doing is displaying a drop down and date picker. It appears that the control is not contained within a form. My goal is to somehow set a value for the date picker control with Mechanize. My language is Python. Is this even possible with Mechanize?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, this won't work with mechanize, as it doesn't support javascript -
it also says so in the [FAQs](http://wwwsearch.sourceforge.net/mechanize/faq.html) and even gives you some [Tipps](http://wwwsearch.sourceforge.net/mechanize/faq.html#script) what you could do instead...